# How can I run docker command inside dokku node.js app?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dokku, prisma

I have node.js application hosted on digital ocean and deployed using dokku. I need to run command `docker-compose up -d` inside this application to start database and Prisma server as mentioned in [prisma docs](https://docs-beta.prisma.io/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-new-database-a002/#start-database-and-prisma-server).

I tried to run `dokku run my-node-js-app "docker-compose up -d"`, but I got this error:

```
Could not determine a reasonable value for WEB_CONCURRENCY.
This is likely due to running the Heroku NodeJS buildpack on a non-Heroku platform.

WEB_CONCURRENCY has been set to 1. Please review whether this value is appropriate for your application.

setuidgid: fatal: unable to run docker-compose: file does not exist
```

I checked, I have `docker-compose.yml` file in my project.

Comment: You might have `docker-compose.yml` present, but you most likely do not have [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) executable installed.

Comment: @AlexKarshin nope, I had it but I didn't have installed `prisma`

Comment: @MaksimGorodov How were you able to run `docker-compose` in your dokku app? I'm getting the following error: `setuidgid: fatal: unable to run docker-compose: file does not exist`. I have docker-compose on the box, but isn't clear how to make it accessible in the dokku app.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install `prisma` by running `npm i -g prisma`